# bootstrap div background-image

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the code used

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Registration</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<link href="twitter-bootstrap/docs/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="twitter-bootstrap/docs/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="twitter-bootstrap/docs/assets/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
    .container
    {
        width: 750px;
        height : 300px;
        margin-top : 50px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class = "container">
<div class = "well" style = "box-shadow : 0 1px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1.0);">    
    <form id = "reg" class = "form-horizontal" method = "post" action = "reg.php">
        <legend>Registration form</legend>      
        <div class = "control-group">
            <label class = "control-label">Login name</label>
            <div class = "controls">
                <div class = "input-prepend">
                    <span class = "add-on"><i class = "icon-user"></i></span>
                        <input type = "text" class = "input-xlarge" id = "login_name" name = "login_name" placeholder = "Login name"><div id = "name_inspector"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here's the function which reacts once an input of the textfield is changed

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //$('#name_inspector').css('background-image', 'url(img/name-is-free.png)');
    $("#login_name").change(
    function()
    {
        $('#name_inspector').css('background-image', 'img/ajax-loader-arrows.gif');
        $.get(
        "is_usr_name_free.php?login_name="+$('#login_name').val(), {},
        // At success.
        function(data)
        {
            var style_arr = data.split('@');
            alert(style_arr[0]+style_arr[1]);
            $('#name_inspector').css(style_arr[0], style_arr[1]);
        }, "html");
    });
```

In the Firebug style is set correctly and picture is loaded. However, there's no picture seen.

Comment: might it be that the name and the id are the same? is there any chance it conflicts?

Comment: No, name_inspector is the only one id with such name in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that an un-styled div has width 100%, and no height. Similarly, a span has no width, but height 100% or the text that's in it. Either way, if there's nothing in the box, then no background will be displayed. You can prove this by adding some text in the div or span. It the difference between in-line and block elements.

So, you either need to specify a height for your div, or a height for the span. That should then create enough space to display the image.

Comment: I renewed the code. Yes I just did. The output is <span id="name_inspector" style="background-image: url("img/name-is-free.png");"></span> and no picture.

Comment: This div does not have styles. I use it as a block to dynamically detect if a name is free to be registered by changing pictures.